# Salesforce as Identity Provider throwing Insufficient Privileges error

Tags: integration, single-sign-on, heroku, node.js

We are implementing a SSO integration, where Salesforce act as the Identity Provider and a NodeJs application in Heroku act as the Service Provider.

We are following this [Github project](https://github.com/enreeco/sf-idp-sso-app) to build the NodeJs application.

Whenever we try to login the NodeJs app with SSO we are facing the following eror from Salesforce.

> **Insufficient Privileges**
>
> You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

We deployed the [Github project](https://github.com/enreeco/sf-idp-sso-app) in heroku and still this error is occuring.
What should be the cause for this error?

**Edit:**
These are the settings I'm passing to Salesforce from my NodeJs app.

> path: '/login/success'
>
> issuer: 'passport-saml'
>
> entryPoint: 'https://melbin-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/idp/endpoint/HttpRedirect'
>
> cert: 'MIIErDCCA ... hNZGSaxWWn'
>
> identifierFormat: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified'

Comment: What are the settings on your web app? Can you post them here?

Comment: @CuriousBlueprints I updated the question and entered the settings I used in my app.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found what caused this issue.
Actually, I entered a wrong URL in ACS URL field of Connected Apps Setup screen in Salesforce. I entered the URL of my NodeJs app and now it is working.